# get the key value when calling matplolib pyplot waitforbuttonpress()

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlib pyplot has a function called `waitforbuttonpress()` which will return either `True` or `False` depending on whether a keyboard or mouse event is received within a graph.
As such mouse events are returned by `waitforbuttonpress()` even if the user interact with the figure using normal graph tools (such as zooming), the only way to use this function is as follows: (assuming the zooming function should be available)

```
while not plt.waitforbuttonpress(): pass  #ignore mouse events use by zomming ...
```

The above will block untill a keyboard key is pressed (as opposed to mouse event which  will be handled normally,e.g. for zooming)

Is there a way to know **which** key was pressed, to distinguish between different choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's directly possible, but you can get the key value from a `key_press_event`, which will be fired at the same time as `waitforbuttonpress()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

the_key = None

def press(event):
    global the_key
    the_key = event.key

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 4, 6])
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
while not plt.waitforbuttonpress(): pass  # ignore mouse events use by zomming ...
print("You pressed: ", the_key)
```